# Refactor jQuery $(this).find

Tags: javascript, jquery, refactoring

I have a written a simple accordion script that works great, I just want to refactor it to get rid of the multiple `$(this).find.

I know it is pretty slim as it is but I hate repeating myself, any ideas? Best way to learn is to ask I suppose.

Thanks!

```js
$.fn.acAccordion = function () {
   $(this).find(".accordion-toggle .acc-state").show();
   $(this).find(".accordion-content").hide();
   $(this).find(".show").show();
  $(this).find(".show").next().show();
  $(this).find('.accordion-toggle').click(function(){
    if($(this).next().is(":hidden")) {
              $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');
    $(".accordion-content").not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');
  }
});
};

$(".accordion").acAccordion();
```

```css
body {
font-size:16px;
font-family:sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="accordion">
  <div class="accordion-toggle show"><span class="accordion-title">Accordion 1</span></div>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    <p>Cras malesuada ultrices augue molestie risus.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-toggle"><span class="accordion-title">Accordion 2</span></div>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
  </p>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-toggle"><span class="accordion-title">Accordion 3</span></div>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    <p>Vivamus facilisisnibh scelerisque laoreet.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You may want to chain those multiple finds with [`.end()`](https://api.jquery.com/end/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I chained calls, removed excess check and calls, reverted order of actions

```js
$.fn.acAccordion = function () {
  $(this).find('.accordion-toggle')
    .click(function() {
      $(this)
        .next().slideDown('fast')
        .siblings('.accordion-content').slideUp('fast');
    })
    .not('.show').next().hide();    
};

$(".accordion").acAccordion();
```

```css
body {
font-size:16px;
font-family:sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="accordion">
  <div class="accordion-toggle show"><span class="accordion-title">Accordion 1</span></div>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    <p>Cras malesuada ultrices augue molestie risus.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-toggle"><span class="accordion-title">Accordion 2</span></div>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
  </p>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-toggle"><span class="accordion-title">Accordion 3</span></div>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    <p>Vivamus facilisisnibh scelerisque laoreet.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly the kind of thing I was looking for, thanks for the heads up!

Comment: @CrisimIlNumenoreano I did - `$(this).find('.accordion-toggle')......not('.show').next().hide();`

Answer (score 0):

You can cache the repeating elements as a start. Also you can chain the calls on the same element:

```js
$.fn.acAccordion = function () {
  var $el = $(this),
    $contents = $el.find('.accordion-content');

  $contents.hide().first().show();

  $el.find('.accordion-toggle').click(function(){
    var $next = $(this).next();

    if ($next.is(":hidden")) {
       $next.slideToggle('fast');
       $contents.not($next).slideUp('fast');
    }
  });
};

$(".accordion").acAccordion();
```

```css
body {
font-size:16px;
font-family:sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="accordion">
  <div class="accordion-toggle show"><span class="accordion-title">Accordion 1</span></div>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    <p>Cras malesuada ultrices augue molestie risus.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-toggle"><span class="accordion-title">Accordion 2</span></div>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
  </p>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-toggle"><span class="accordion-title">Accordion 3</span></div>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    <p>Vivamus facilisisnibh scelerisque laoreet.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you beated me for 2 secs.... if the OP doesn't like the `.find()` statement he could use `$toggles = $(".accordion-toggle", $el)` syntax

Comment: Improved the response and made it a snippet for easier testing.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

https://jsfiddle.net/n2hdkede/

```
$(function(){

    $.fn.acAccordion = function () {
         $(".accordion-title")
         .on("click", function(e){
             $(".accordion-content:visible").slideUp("fast");
             $(e.target).parent()
             .next().slideDown();            
         });
    }
    $(".accordion").acAccordion();

});
```

Hide any visible .accordion-content divs

Comment: with this you can't have more than one accordion in a page

Comment: I personally don't hide element with CSS for things like this because if the user visits with JS turned off they have no way to view the content. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: Nothing is hidden until you click on a `.accordion-title` so all the content is visible for people with JS turned off. `$(".accordion-content:visible").slideUp("fast")` means "slide them up if they're visible". That's what i was referring to in the last sentence :).